# Allegro: plotted artwork only has hatched pads

Tags: allegro

I am trying to find my way around Cadence Allegro. My aim is to make a PDF file with the copper mask.

I made a schematic with capture, created a PCB layout with Allegro PCB Designer and created artwork using Manufacture->Artwork.

I then imported this artwork into Allegro and selected File->Plot and printed via a PDF printer. My problem is that the copper for the pads is not filled solidly but with thin lines. Why is this so and how can I get solid filling?

See the attached example:

- even very thick lines are solid
- pads are hatched only

[image]

Comment: Is your goal to get the pdf to look right, or to make sure the board will be fabricated correctly?

Comment: @Justin I think in my case those are identical. The pdf is used as an optical mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem is that I was trying to print a photomask from gerber files.

The entire "Manufacture" step is unnecessary. [This document](http://userweb.eng.gla.ac.uk/john.davies/orcad/pcbdesigner.pdf) explains how to print photomasks directly from the layout. The result is as it should be:

[image]

Comment: Where are your bypass caps for that device?